# Zurb foundation accordion in dynamic html and javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using handlebars/hamlbars to create dynamic html, and the dynamic html uses zurb to style an accordion but unfortunately the javascript part (show/hide contents) of the accordion doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included modernizr.js in your application?  Most of the JavaScript Foundation uses relies on it.

The easiest way to install it is to use the modernizr-rails gem
https://github.com/russfrisch/modernizr-rails